# How to active the 'nav-link disabled' using jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
 - List item

    <ul class="nav nav-tabs-outline">
                <li class="nav-item">
                  <a class="nav-link active" data-toggle="tab" href="#shot-Title">Title</a>
                </li>
                <li class="nav-item">
                  <a class="nav-link disabled" data-toggle="tab" href="#shot-Description" id="disco">Description</a>
                </li>
                <li class="nav-item">
                  <a class="nav-link disabled" data-toggle="tab" href="#shot-Details">Details</a>
                </li>
                <li class="nav-item">
                  <a class="nav-link disabled" data-toggle="tab" href="#shot-Skills">Exprtise and Skills</a>
                </li>
                  <li class="nav-item">
                  <a class="nav-link disabled" data-toggle="tab" href="#shot-Budget">Budget</a>
                </li>
              </ul>
```

```
JavaScript

 <script type='text/javascript' src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

        <script type='text/javascript'>
            $(document).ready(function(){
                $('#jobpostname').keyup(function () {
                    if ($(this).val() == '') {
                        //Check to see if there is any text entered
                        // If there is no text within the input then disable the button
                        $('#disco').prop('disabled', true);

                    } else {
                        //If there is text in the input, then enable the button
                        $('#disco').prop('disabled', false);
                    }
                });
            }); 
        </script>
```

There is a input element in title tag , what i want to do is when i type something in  title input  the description link should get activated ,
is there a way  to active the 'nav-link disabled' using jquery?

Answer (score 1):

Hi **Aksingh** welcome to Stackoverflow's community.

In your code `disabled` and `active` are classes not attributes or properties.

So you can use jQuery's `addClass` and `removeClass` methods to solve your problem

*try this code*..

```
$(document).ready(function(){
        $('#jobpostname').keyup(function () {
            if ($(this).val() == '') {
                //Check to see if there is any text entered
                // If there is no text within the input then disable the button
                $('#disco').addClass('disabled');
                $('#disco').removeClass('active'); 

            } else {
                //If there is text in the input, then enable the button
                $('#disco').addClass('active');
                $('#disco').removeClass('disabled');
            }
        });
    });
```

Comment: Thanks its working , but the content inside the Description Listed items 'href="#shot-Description"' which is a div  is not opening.